# unsafe.compareAndSwapObject replacing an array that is being iterated in another thread

Tags: java, arrays, concurrency, unsafe, sun

I am trying to implement logic that will allow me to update an array in one thread using sun's unsafe.compareAndSwapObject utility while safely iterating over that same array, in a different thread. I believe that the CopyOnWriteArrayList does what I am searching for however it uses locking for the updating and I am trying to develop a solution that does not have any locks.

The compare and swap logic is as follows:

```
public void add(final Object toAdd) {
    Object[] currentObjects;
    Object[] newObjects;
    do {
        currentObjects = this.objects;
        newObjects = ArrayUtil.add(currentObjects, toAdd);
    } while (!UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject(this, OBJECTS_OFFSET, currentObjects, newObjects));
}
```

While the iteration logic is as follows (the toString() is a placeholder):

```
public void doWork() {
    Object[] currentObjects = this.objects;
    for (final Object object : currentObjects) {
        object.toString();
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is this code safe?
2. Does this give me the same snapshot behaviour that CopyOnWriteArrayList does?
3. If it does, when is the iteration snapshot formed?

   - Does the fact that I'm creating a local variable have anything to do this?
   - If it does, how does the JVM know to not optimise this away?
   - Have I essentially created a variable on the stack that has a reference to the most up to date array object?

Lastly to follow up the third point above about "snapshot" creation, would the following code work the same way:

```
public void doWork() {
    actuallyDoWork(this.objects);
}

public void actuallyDoWork() {
    for (final Object object : currentObjects) {
        object.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your root problem? Avoiding `CME` can be done easier than that, and it's the array creation that takes most time in `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, not the locking. Your approach can create multiple arrays while spinning in the `CAS`. You also haven't shown the iterator code, so I'd say it's not an alternative to a tried and tested class like `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Comment: The iteration happens in `doWork` and `actuallyDoWork`. I'm just curious and would like to build an alternative to `CopyOnWriteArrayList` that does not use locks.

Comment: You haven't written any iterator code. The foreach loop uses an iterator internally, so unless you've written that code, it can't work. But like I said, even if it did work, your implementation would be worse both in performance and quality.